# Selenium Hidden Elements: Hidden <option> Elements Within <select>

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select a particular option within a select box on a webpage.  http://www.arnoldporter.com/news.cfm.

Specifically I want to selection "FDA and Healthcare" option within the Practice/Industry selection box.

I have tried a number of things, including clicking on the select tag, and then clicking on the FDA option.  I have also checked to see whether the select tag changes after being clicked on.  It doesn't.

So, Nothing seems to work, I keep getting the same error: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

The xpath I am using for the select box is: `//select[@class="medium" and @name="search_practice_id"]`

The xpath I am using for the option is: `//option[@value="323"]`

There must be a simple solution, I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

URL          = 'http://www.arnoldporter.com/news.cfm'
CSS_SELECTOR = 'select[name=search_practice_id][class=medium]'
OPTION_TEXT  = 'FDA and Healthcare'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
select_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(CSS_SELECTOR)
select = Select(select_el)
select.select_by_visible_text(OPTION_TEXT)
```